# "deprecated from Graph API 2.9" warnings for FBSDKShareLinkContent properties

Tags: ios, swift, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

When I try to pass an `FBSDKShareLinkContent` to an `FBSDKMessageDialog`, it returns with warnings for some properties, saying that those are deprecated from Graph API 2.9.

> 'imageURL' is deprecated: `imageURL` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9
>
> 'contentTitle' is deprecated: `contentTitle` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9
>
> 'contentDescription' is deprecated: `contentDescription` is deprecated from Graph API 2.9

What can I do in order to prevent this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The methods that allow attaching a link to posts now retreive the image, the title and the description from proprietary `meta` tags and not from the code itself. Simply remove the lines to get rid of the warnings and set up the proper tags on the site itself.

[See the exact deprecation changelog here.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.8#gapi-deprecate)

Comment: I have no access to the backend so I can't setup Open Graph on it. I need to post URL and image. Am I completely out of luck?

Comment: @PavelAlexeev I'm in the same spot you are right now - you find any work around? I'm using JS though as opposed to ios.

Answer (score 2):

So you are not alowed to use those properties anymore (graph 2.9) when you are sharing a link via facebook. All the informations facebook needs will be gathered from the  "og" tags ("og:title", etc..) in the web page meta tags you want to share.

In the   element of your web content you should have :

```
<meta property="og:title" content="your content"/>
<meta property="og:description" content="your content"/>
```

Comment: Can you share a link to this document?